# Safari Conditional CSS

Tags: css, safari

How can I add css to be only read by safari? bascially a div needs moving 5pixels to the left, as it shows fine on ff/ie etc

Thanks

EDIT - added code

code:

```
#subheading
{
background-color: #004376;
color: #ffffff;
height: 25px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 933px;
margin-top: -25px;
width: 761px;   
}
```

Comment: Code to the site would be useful - I'd say it's very unlikely this is a Webkit bug, and that you could change the way you've coded it and it will work properly.

Answer (score 5):

you can have a check for a specific css property in webkit. This would likely work in chrome as well.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        .someClass{
            color:#FF0000;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to be a safari only bug? any chance I could get it only for this.

Comment: Are you sure the bug isn't in chrome also? I think they have the same rendering engine.

Comment: yup I just checked and it looks fine.

Comment: Safari uses the same rendering engine as Google Chrome (webkit), so it's unlikely to have a problem occur in only one of the those.

If it truly only occurs on Safari, you might consider a Javascript solution. Even better, try to figure out why the problem is really happening and figure out a way to avoid browser-specific CSS.

Comment: Thanks I have checked on both mac and pc and its only in Safari, I have added the code above its the margin it seems to be having a problem with.

Comment: I have a poroblem with Google Fonts, which occurs on Safari, but not on Chrome.

I guess I will have to use some php browser detection to solve the issue then.

Comment: The answer doesn't address the question about safari-specific css

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 0 933px;
margin-top: -25px;
width: 761px;
```

This doesn't sound right. The first line sets both left and right margin to 933px. And the width is 761px. The total width of the element would be `(933 * 2 + 10 * 2 + 761) = 2647px`.

Is this what you want it to be?

Comment: I thought it would be something to do with this, but it seems to show fine on everything but safari. What would be the fix? thanks

Comment: You may have other overrides. Can you post a link to your page or a small test case that reproduces your problem?

Comment: What should it look like? It looks the same in IE8, Firefox, Chrome to me.

Comment: Safari(Win) too. The page you've linked appears the same in all browsers. I did not see any difference in Safari. The subheader is rendered towards the far right side of the menu bar.